# How to fix link error of OpenVINO sample on Raspberry PI

Tags: raspbian-jessie, openvino

I have raspberry pi 3 B+ with Raspbian Jessi on it it. I am trying to setup it to run OpenVINO applications. I was following the installation steps as per the [documentation](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_raspbian.html) and it went fine.

When I tried to build and run Object Detection Sample following the same steps in the mentioned documentation it actually build fine but failed at linking giving the following error:

```
[ 96%] Linking CXX shared library ../armv7l/Release/lib/libcpu_extension.so
[ 96%] Built target ie_cpu_extension
Scanning dependencies of target object_detection_sample_ssd
[ 98%] Building CXX object object_detection_sample_ssd/CMakeFiles/object_detection_sample_ssd.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../armv7l/Release/object_detection_sample_ssd
CMakeFiles/object_detection_sample_ssd.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `showAvailableDevices()':
main.cpp:(.text._Z20showAvailableDevicesv[_Z20showAvailableDevicesv]+0x18): undefined reference to `InferenceEngine::Core::Core(std::string const&)'

...

make[3]: *** [armv7l/Release/object_detection_sample_ssd] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:632: recipe for target 'object_detection_sample_ssd/CMakeFiles/object_detection_sample_ssd.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [object_detection_sample_ssd/CMakeFiles/object_detection_sample_ssd.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:644: recipe for target 'object_detection_sample_ssd/CMakeFiles/object_detection_sample_ssd.dir/rule' failed
make[1]: *** [object_detection_sample_ssd/CMakeFiles/object_detection_sample_ssd.dir/rule] Error 2
Makefile:292: recipe for target 'object_detection_sample_ssd' failed
make: *** [object_detection_sample_ssd] Error 2
```

I am not sure what is the problem or how I can debug it. Can you help me to build and run the model please?

Comment: `Operating Systems

Raspbian* Buster, 32-bit
Raspbian* Stretch, 32-bit
Software

CMake* 3.7.2 or higher
Python* 3.5, 32-bit` Your config don't match because you use Jessie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using **Raspbian Jessie**. This version is deprecated and its support has finished last year. Also [the tutorial you are using](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_raspbian.html) notes in section

> Development and Target Platforms
>   . Operating Systems
>   .... Raspbian* Buster, 32-bit
>   .... Raspbian* Stretch, 32-bit

**Raspbian Jessie** does not match this condition so what you try cannot work. You should really use **Raspbian Buster** now.

Comment: Yes, when I setup a new SD Card with a fresh installation (it was recommended not to upgrade to Buster on the website) it compiled OK. Thank you

Comment: @aibrahim Can you please accept the answer with a click on the tick on its left side? Only accepting an answer will finish your question and it will not pop up again and again for years (and for nothing).